# How do I develop on top of forked repo?

Tags: git

We have a major repo called `team_repo/project`, my teammate forked from it, called `teammate/project`. Then he made some commits to his `feature` branch and pushed to `teammate/project` already but has not sent out a pull request to `team_repo/project`. And now I am asked to build on top of his `feature` branch and eventually commit the changes to the `main` branch of `team_repo/project`, what git commands will I need so that I can preserve both his work and mine in the PR to `team_repo/project`?

Comment: Don't build on top of unmerged work. That's a recipe for wasted effort.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the comment, but the reality is my teammate is not available to continue building stuffs to `feature` branch and I must take over the remaining work.

Comment: Add your teammate repo as a new remote and fetch. You should be able to see the feature remote branch. Create a local branch there and now the feature branch is yours...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your teammates work by adding their remote:

`git remote add teammate url`

Where teammate is the name you want to refer to the remote as, and url is the url your teammates forked repo.

`git fetch teammate` to pull down the branches.

You should be able to merge branches then. Use `git branch -r` to check they have come through.

`git checkout teammate/feature` assuming your teammates branch was called `feature`.

`git checkout -b teammates-feature` to create a branch on the `main` repo with your teammates code.

`git checkout -b my-feature` to create a copy that you can work on.

Now you have both branches on your local.

As far as preserving, you can then push these branches to `main` remote and create separate pull requests.